# How to Increment a nvarchar value + number when more then one value is displayed for a given ID

Tags: sql-server

I need to add a address type value to a column when more then one value is returned from the query below. For example if  a single result is returned then I want the value in the address type column to be Business. But if there is more then one value returned, I want it to increment a value after the first result to be Alternate Business 1,Alternate Business 2, Alternate Business 3 etc.

Can anyone help me out?

```
SELECT al.ADDRESS_ID,
       addr.LINE1 + ' (' + addr.LABEL + ')' AS ModifiedLine1,
       addr2.ADDR_TYP_ID,
       addr2.LABEL,
       addr2.LINE2,
       addr2.LINE3,
       addr2.CITY,
       addr2.STATE,
       addr2.COUNTRY,
       addr2.POSTAL_CD
FROM   INT_AUX_LST_ADDR al
       LEFT JOIN INT_AUX_ADDRESS addr
              ON addr.ADDRESS_ID = al.ADDRESS_ID
       LEFT JOIN INT_AUX_ADDRESS addr2
              ON addr2.ADDRESS_ID = al.ADDRESS_ID
       LEFT JOIN INT_RELATION_TYP rt
              ON rt.RLTN_TYP_ID = al.RLTN_TYP_ID
WHERE  al.LISTING_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `row_number()` . . .  The only caveat is that you need some ordering.  But here it goes:

```
SELECT al.ADDRESS_ID,
       addr.LINE1 + ' (' + addr.LABEL + ')' AS ModifiedLine1,
       addr2.ADDR_TYP_ID,
       addr2.LABEL,
       addr2.LINE2,
       addr2.LINE3,
       addr2.CITY,
       addr2.STATE,
       addr2.COUNTRY,
       addr2.POSTAL_CD,
       (case row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
             when 1 then 'Business'
             else 'Alternate Business '+cast(-1 + row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as varchar(255))
        end) as WhatYouWant
FROM   INT_AUX_LST_ADDR al
       LEFT JOIN INT_AUX_ADDRESS addr
              ON addr.ADDRESS_ID = al.ADDRESS_ID
       LEFT JOIN INT_AUX_ADDRESS addr2
              ON addr2.ADDRESS_ID = al.ADDRESS_ID
       LEFT JOIN INT_RELATION_TYP rt
              ON rt.RLTN_TYP_ID = al.RLTN_TYP_ID
WHERE  al.LISTING_ID = 1 ;
```

By the way, with the indeterminate `order by` in the example above, there is no guarantee that the two `row_number()` calls return the same values -- but in practice they will.  If you replace it with the correct field for ordering, then this is not a problem.